# What map projection is this ? is it Dymaxion map (Fuller)?

Tags: coordinate-system

What  map projection is this ? is it Fuller ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details, for example where did you find this map, maybe someone can find some hints ?

Comment: "What projection is this?" is more of a general geography Question than a GIS one.

Comment: [ob XKCD](https://xkcd.com/977/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Peirce quincuncial projection.  See [Wikipedia Peirce quincuncial projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection) for details